# update a dataframe in pandas while iterating

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I Need to iterate values in a dataframe .In a data frame where i have oldvalue and new value columns in dataframe . I want to

```
old value    newvalue  date       casenumber
aab          baa       1/1/2019     001
acb          bca       2/2/2019     002
abc          cba       1/7/2109     003
acd          dca       2/8/2019     004
aab          bca       2/23/2019    005
acb          baa       4/6/2019     006
abc          dca       4/9/2019     007
aab          baa       1/23/2019    008
```

I want to iterate the values in oldvalue to know how many are passing from oldvalue  to new value from aab to others.

expected output:-

```
         jan   feb  march  April
aab-baa   2                 1    
aab-bca         1
acb-bca         1
acb-baa                     4
abc-cba    1
abc-dca                      4
acd-dca         1
```

The code i used to get the output:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"")
f8 = df[df['Old Value'] == 'aab'] every time i am changing   the old value manually  
f9 = f8[f8['New Value'] == 'baa'] 
f1 = f8[f8['New Value'] == 'bca'] 
f2 = f8[f8['New Value'] == 'cba']
f3 = f8[f8['New Value'] == 'dca']
f4 = f8[f8['New Value'] == 'abc']

d1 = pd.concat([f9, f1])
d2 = pd.concat([f2, f3])
d3 = pd.concat([d1, d2])
d4= pd.concat([d3, f4])

df10=d4[['Case Number','Old Value','New Value']]
f9= df10.set_index(["New Value", "Old Value"]).count(level="New Value") 


df = pd.read_excel(r"")
f8 = df[df['Old Value'] == 'aab'] 
f9 = f8[f8['New Value'] == 'baa'] 
f1 = f8[f8['New Value'] == 'bca'] 
f2 = f8[f8['New Value'] == 'cba']
f3 = f8[f8['New Value'] == 'dca']
f4 = f8[f8['New Value'] == 'abc']
d1 = pd.concat([f9, f1])
d2 = pd.concat([f2, f3])
d3 = pd.concat([d1, d2])
d4= pd.concat([d3, f4])
df10=d4[['Case Number','Old Value','New Value']]
f9= df10.set_index(["New Value", "Old Value"]).count(level="New Value")
```

out put

```
             jan   feb  march  April
    aab-baa   2                  1    
    aab-bca         1
    acb-bca         1
    acb-baa                      4
    abc-cba   1
    abc-dca                      4
    acd-dca         1
```

Comment: Can you clarify your expected output?

Comment: i want count of cases changing from old value to new value according  data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert `date`s to datetimes, then reshape by [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) for correct order, add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for all missing months (if necessary), then convert columns to months and last convert `MultiIndex` to first 2 columns:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = (pd.crosstab([df['old value'],df['newvalue']], df['date'].dt.month)
        .reindex(columns=range(1, 13), fill_value=0)
        .rename(columns = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m').strftime('%b'))
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
  old value newvalue  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  \
0       aab      baa    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   
1       aab      bca    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   
2       abc      cba    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   
3       abc      dca    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   
4       acb      baa    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   
5       acb      bca    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   
6       acd      dca    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   

   Dec  
0    0  
1    0  
2    0  
3    0  
4    0  
5    0  
6    0
```

Replace `0` to empty strings is possible, but get numeric with strings data and next processing should be problem:

```
df = (pd.crosstab([df['old value'],df['newvalue']], df['date'].dt.month)
        .replace(0, '')
        .reindex(columns=range(1, 13), fill_value='')
        .rename(columns = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m').strftime('%b'))
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
  old value newvalue Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
0       aab      baa   2                                            
1       aab      bca       1                                        
2       abc      cba   1                                            
3       abc      dca               1                                
4       acb      baa               1                                
5       acb      bca       1                                        
6       acd      dca       1
```